# Is this heteroscedasticity or something else?

Tags: residuals, heteroscedasticity

Here are my residuals versus my fitted values.

[image]

I am not sure how to interpret this. The upper blue line is decreasing (I drew this myself, it's not some fancy estimate), but the lower blue line stays somewhat constant, instead of increasing.

If the lower increased, I would say it is heteroscedasticity, but since it doesn't, I am not sure what the issue in this plot is, if any at all?

Comment: Envelopes -- even those ignoring possible outliers as a matter of judgment -- don't work so well when the density of points is variable across the plot, which it usually is in practice. I would not call out heteroscedastic unless something like a scatter plot smooth of $|$residual$|^{1/2}$ was definitely not flat. I am a fan of looking at observed versus fitted too, even though in principle it's the same information.

Comment: @Nick is, of course, correct in general. In this particular case, though, my eye suggests there is a pattern of decreasing variance from left to right--but it's difficult to characterize due to the overlapping of points in the middle.  Consider plotting "traces" of this cloud: run a moving window from left to right, constructed to comprise $k$ points (with $k$ specified somewhere between a few dozen and few hundred--experiment with its value). Trace out the $\alpha$ and $1-\alpha$ quantiles of residuals within the windows, where $\alpha$ is somewhere between $.05$ and $.25$ (experiment).

Comment: A graph like this looks unusual because more commonly any heteroscedasticity runs the other way. The context may suggest a different model in any case.

Comment: @Nick If you like to see increasing variance, just negate the fitted values :-).  Notice that will make most of them positive, too, which is more "usual."  There's obviously more structure here, though, than mere heteroscedasticity. *E.g.*, the skewness decreases from positive to zero (and perhaps becomes a little negative, even).  That's why more delicate diagnostic plots would be worthwhile: one needs to explore how and (if possible) why the residual distribution varies.

Comment: @whuber You've looked at it longer -- and crucially much more carefully than I have. My guesses are that the outcome is already a logarithm. I suspect also an upper bound.